# Socket Connection issues connecting between two sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

## I would like to create a socket to connect between client an server using the port of my choice. I am getting the error code below.

## Client Side Code

```
import socket
import time
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 5555))
clientsocket.send('42.222,93457345345,0\n')
time.sleep(5)
clientsocket.send('42.222,93457345345,0\n')
time.sleep(5)
clientsocket.send('42.222,93457345345,0\n')
time.sleep(5)
clientsocket.send('42.222,93457345345,0\n')
time.sleep(5)
```

## Server Side Code

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 5555))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections


while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = ''
    while True:
        buf = buf+connection.recv(5)
        if '\n' not in buf:
            continue
        else:
            while '\n' in buf:
                message_end=buf.find('\n')
                message=buf[:message_end]
                print (message)
                message.split(',')
                buf=buf[message_end+1:]
```

## Im getting this error code whenever I run the program

## Client Error Code:

```
C:\Scripts\python.exe C:/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/GooMPy-master/client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/GooMPy-master/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    clientsocket.send('42.222,93457345345,0\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

## Server Side Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/GooMPy-master/server.py", line 12, in <module>
    buf = buf+connection.recv(5)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data (String) to Bytes.

Use for literals:

```
clientsocket.send(b'42.222,93457345345,0\n')
```

or for varialabes:

```
my_string = '42.222,93457345345,0\n'
clientsocket.send(my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

Decode at server site with:

```
data = received_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Since the return value of recv() is a bytes object representing the data received, i'd say: `buf = buf + connection.recv(5).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: otherwise you can do this:
`data = connection.recv(5)`
`buf = buf + data.decode('utf-8')`